# What's with the '@' symbols in this C code?

Tags: c

I'm digging around the guts of [NumPy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy), trying to figure out why it's not building for me (64-bit [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and [Windows 8.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8.1)), I've come to [this file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math.c.src).

When compilation hits the `rad2deg()` function (pasted below), I get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). Looking at the file, there are a **ton** of '@' symbols sprinkled throughout the code. It *looks* like some kind of wildcard token, or a preprocessor token, but I can't find any information on it anywhere.

```
#define LOGE2    NPY_LOGE2@c@
#define LOG2E    NPY_LOG2E@c@
#define RAD2DEG  (180.0@c@/NPY_PI@c@)
#define DEG2RAD  (NPY_PI@c@/180.0@c@)

@type@ npy_rad2deg@c@(@type@ x) {
    return x*RAD2DEG;
}`
```

There are other places in the code where compiler doesn't choke with the '@' characters.

Is there a search term that might explain this?

Comment: It looks like they have their own preprocessor that substitutes those symbols based on the comments above.

Comment: Do you mean the compiler issues a segfault? What compiler are you using?

Comment: Yes, the compiler issues a segfault. And I think Slaks is right and that this is a red herring; this seems to be some kind of preprocessing thing that expands these code chunks out into multiple functions.

Comment: For general entertainment and wisdom, what kind of compiler treats @ like the killer poke?

Comment: In short: dont play hide&seek with the preprocessor. Youll lose.

Comment: To be 100% clear, you get a segmentation fault at compile time, right? An `@` character shouldn't cause that; it should cause the compiler to report a syntax error. Then again, *nothing* should cause the compiler to seg fault. It's a bug in the compiler. But to track it down, you should figure out how that input is processed before being fed to the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I've figured it out.

This is some non-standard pre-pre-processor trick, probably implemented in the Python code which builds the C code for NumPy.

```
/**begin repeat
 * #type = npy_float, npy_double, npy_longdouble#
 * #c = f, ,l#
 * #C = F, ,L#
 */

#define LOGE2    NPY_LOGE2@c@
#define LOG2E    NPY_LOG2E@c@
#define RAD2DEG  (180.0@c@/NPY_PI@c@)
#define DEG2RAD  (NPY_PI@c@/180.0@c@)

@type@ npy_rad2deg@c@(@type@ x)
{
    return x*RAD2DEG;
}

/**end repeat**/
```

It iterates across the code, replacing the @-surrounded tokens in the code with the tokens in the comment block, generating three nearly identical code blocks operating on different data types.

I suspect the segfault may be coming from improper data types; we'll see.

Comment: Does the compiler itself die with a seg fault? If so, that's a bug in the compiler. Improper data types should only result in an error message, never a compile-time crash.