# What does @gint@ do?

Tags: glib

I started to try and compile something and I went down a rabbit hole when I saw this error:

```
gitrepos/glib/glib/glibconfig.h:47:16: error: stray ‘@’ in program
   47 | typedef signed @gint16@ gint16;
```

What does a value enclosed in at signs do? I can't find any documentation on it.
I'm trying to learn about wireplumber so I set up a file which initializes it:https://pastebin.com/AuPSckXi.

The full error is:https://pastebin.com/W5d4nBKP, and it is returned from

```
g++ -c -I/home/whitequill/gitrepos/wireplumber/lib/wp -I/home/whitequill/gitrepos/glib -I/home/whitequill/gitrepos/glib/glib ./initialize_wireplumber.c -o ./pw
```

I don't have glib cause I installed KDE on Gentoo and I wanted a quick work-around so as not to need to install glib.
For reference the code I pulled that has the `@` is here:https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/wireplumber/-/blob/master/lib/wp/core.h.

Comment: actually its `glibconfig.h.in` which I made a sym link to.

Comment: Possibly related: *[What's with the '@' symbols in this C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850445/whats-with-the-symbols-in-this-c-code?rq=3)* and *[Use of the @ symbol in C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783319/use-of-the-symbol-in-c-programming?rq=3)*

Comment: Why did you make a symlink to `glibconfig.h.in`? That’s not how to build GLib. `glibconfig.h` needs to be generated from `glibconfig.h.in` using Meson. The `@` symbols indicate a substitution which will be performed by Meson.

Comment: Re *"I started to try and compile something"*: Can you reveal more? Compiler, incl. version. Environment (IDE, operating system). The compilation process (build system and/or command lines to start the compilation). The version of GLib. The actual code. Etc. Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76488907/edit), not here in comments (but *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).